# LiFePo4 cell risk of explosion during cool down

Tags: lifepo4

A 3 Ah LFP cell is charged to 100% at 25°C temperature.
What happenes if I cool down the charged cell to -20 °C temperature?
At -20 °C the cell can store only 2 Ah. 
Does it mean, the cell is overcharged by 1 Ah, equivalent to 30 %?
Is there a risk that the cell will explode?

I assume, that this cell would be protected by the BMS in a battery configuration, if the overcharge causes an overvoltage.
In this case, the BMS should dissipate the 1 Ah overcharge in order to not exceed the max cell voltage.

Answer (score 4):

That's not how it works.

What happens is that under low temperatures you cannot extract more than 2 Ah out of a fully charged cell because internal resistance rises under low temperature. The voltage of the charged cell will not change.